# Spring data jpa how to find the subclass discriminator value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have set up inheritance, with few subclasses. I get an id, and i want to be able to send a query that give me back the discriminator from which i can call the correct repository and get the full inflated class.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gives descriminator:

SELECT Type(d) FROM object d

gives class:

@Query("select e.class from AbstractEvent e where e.id = :id")